# Let the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ have the topology $\mathcal{T}$ as shown in the picture.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Note that $\{b\}$ is open and not closed, $\{a\}$ is closed and not open, $\{a,b\}$ is both open and closed, and $\{b,c\}$ is neither open nor closed.I am trying to convince myself that the above sets mentioned are open, closed, both open and closed, and neither open nor closed.

Here are my thoughts:

$\mathcal{T}=\{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b\},\{b\},\{b,c,d\},\{c,d\}\}$. So $\{b\}$ is open because it is in the topology. $\{a\}$ is closed because if you take any above set in the topology and subtract $\{a\}$ you get a set in the topology.

I am having trouble seeing why $\{a,b\}$ is both open and closed. I did this:
$\{a,b,c,d\}-\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$, $\{a,b\}-\{a,b\}=\{\}$, $\{b\}-\{a,b\}=\{\}$, $\{b,c,d\}-\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$, and $\{c,d\}-\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$. Since all of the complements are open, wouldn't that mean that $\{a,b\}$ is closed?

Also I am having the same issue with convincing myself that $\{b,c\}$ is neither open or closed.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: {$a,b$} is open because it’s in the topology and closed because its complement {$c,d$} is open; on the other hand, {$b,c$} is not in the topology nor is its complement {$a,d$}

Comment: Sweet. That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what it means for a set to be closed in a topology $\mathcal{T}$. By definition, a set is closed if its complement is an open set. So to verify that $\{a,b\}$ is closed, simply notice that
$$\{a,b,c,d\}-\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}\text{ is an open set.}$$
Here by complement I mean the complement with respect to the universal set. In this case, the universal set is $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

So the definition of closed is *not* "take any above set in the topology and subtract...".

Comment: "By definition, a set is closed if it's complement is an open set." -- Eh, that depends on your definition. For instance, my own metric spaces class defined it as a set which contains its own limit points. But that can be shown to be equivalent at least.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer The OP is asking about open/closed sets in a topological space, not a metric space which is a specific instance of a topological space.

Comment: 1. $\{a,b\}$ is open because it belongs to the collection of open sets. Indeed, the collection of open sets is, as the picture defined it, the five sets you listed out. 2. Now, $\{a,b\}$ is closed because it's complement $\{a,b,c,d\}-\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$ belong to the collection of open sets. No further reasoning is needed.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your clear response.